# AngularJs StateProvider is passing ? in the queryString

Tags: angularjs

http://localhost:8080/restEzJson/#/login

This should be url on which Login should work but when I enter credentials and post the data via RestEASY to validate it then even though data is valid, it is redirecting me to below URL

http://localhost:8080/restEzJson/?#/login

On this URL it working fine.

I want function through first URL rather in the second.

It is working fine in Firefox but not in Chrome.